# Liveweave vs jsfiddle and codepen - Same code, different results

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, gridjs

I'm using liveweave to design an app. Right now everything is working fine on the console of this editor. However, when I downloaded the code and tried it in Google Chrome, I noticed that my table overflowed beyond the limit of the container. I tried to use the same code in codepen and jsfiddle and the results are the same as in Chrome. Is there any reason for the same code to work in some editors but fail in others? I'm using gridjs for the table. I'm forcing the height of the table to be 100% regarding the container.

Here is the code:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

    <script type="module">
        import {
        Grid,
        html
    } from "https://unpkg.com/gridjs?module";
    </script>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>   
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            <div class="col-5">
                <!--<div id="fixed-alert">-->
                <div class="card h-100" id="card2">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <table id="alert_table" class="table">
                            <tbody id="alert_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="ratio" style="--bs-aspect-ratio: 40%;">
                                            <div id="table"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

```
new gridjs.Grid({
    columns: ["Name", "Email", "Phone Number"],
    sort: true,
    pagination: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    //width: document.getElementById("table").clientWidth,
    data: [
        ["John", "john@example.com", "(353) 01 222 3333"],
        ["Mark", "mark@gmail.com", "(01) 22 888 4444"],
        ["Eoin", "eoin@gmail.com", "0097 22 654 00033"],
        ["Sarah", "sarahcdd@gmail.com", "+322 876 1233"],
        ["Afshin", "afshin@mail.com", "(353) 22 87 8356"],
        ["Afshin", "afshin@mail.com", "(353) 22 87 8356"],
        ["Afshin", "afshin@mail.com", "(353) 22 87 8356"],
        ["Afshin", "afshin@mail.com", "(353) 22 87 8356"]
    ]
}).render(document.getElementById("table"));
```

Comment: will be helpful if you can share links of those editors with the code you have mentioned, it is a little extra to expect people to go and try this code in all the editors to verify your issue

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I'm not understanding. Can you point out the issue please?